# How can I render a string in React JS which has components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, string, jsx, render

I have a String and want to render it in react JS

```
const htmlString = "<h1>
<Ref description=\"Magic may or may not be happening\"> hello magic</Ref></h1>"
return ( <div> <h1>
{htmlString}</h1>
 </div\>)
```

Can I render this htmlString in react js Please help!

Comment: setInnerHtml or use a library

Comment: dangerouslySetInnerHtml: https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use **dangerouslySetInnerHTML** attribute on an html element to set the string as HTML. But know that setting HTML like this in React is risky as this may expose your users to a cross-site scripting (XSS) attack.
To know more on how to use it, refer here on official React docs:
https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml

Posting an example use-case below on how to use it.

```js
function App() {
  
  function getMarkup() {
    return {__html: '<h3>My Content here..</h3>'}; // The HTML string you want to set
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={getMarkup()}></div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: sorry Its just rendering Html tags not react component

Comment: Even if you figure out how to render a component from string, the code might result into an error if that component is not imported. This will make it unreliable. But still if you want to achieve, you may want to try using React.createElement, refer here: [React createElement](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement)

Answer (score -1):

You can use `react-html-parser` to achieve this

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactHtmlParser from 'react-html-parser';
 
class HtmlComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const html = '<div>Example HTML string</div>';
    return <div>{ ReactHtmlParser(html) }</div>;
  }
}
```

See docs [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-html-parser)

Comment: sorry Its just rendering Html tags not react component